# Rails' strip_tags is not even close to being as good as PHP's strip_tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The rails' version of `strip_tags()` **doesn't seem to remove javascript and css code blocks?**

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Which version or ruby are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the [Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) gem for this which as standard strips out everything and just leaves plain text.

The example from GitHub is ...

```
html = '<b><a href="http://foo.com/">foo</a></b><img src="http://foo.com/bar.jpg">'

Sanitize.clean(html) # => 'foo'
```